# .Net DataView and DataTable Binding

Tags: .net, data-binding, datatable, dataview

I have a simple Windows Forms application which binds a DataView to a ListBox. This DataView uses Linq to sort my DataTable by a specific column descending. My ListBox is then bound to the DataView. I then have a simple form to add data to the DataTable. When I add a DataRow to the DataTable it displays in the ListBox.

I'm curious as to whats going on behind the scenes... [I've read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983707%28VS.71%29.aspx):

> A DataView object is a customized view
>   of a single data table that may be
>   filtered or sorted. A data view is the
>   data "snapshot" used by complex-bound
>   controls. You can simple- or
>   complex-bind to the data within a data
>   view, but be aware that you are
>   binding to a fixed "picture" of the
>   data rather than a clean, updating
>   data source.

I would have thought that since the DataView is a "snapshot" it wouldn't have automatically updated. Does a DataView add an event to update when the underlying DataTable is modified? Don't get me wrong, this is how I want it to work, but is this always the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataView` is not a snapshot. It is updated automatically and immediately as the underlying `DataTable` changes. New rows added to the `DataTable` that meet the `DataView`'s filter criteria will automatically appear in the `DataView`. Similarly, rows removed from the `DataTable` will automatically disappear from the `DataView`.

The following illustrates the dynamic nature of the `DataView` even when using LINQ:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");

            var query = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                        where row.Field<string>("FirstName").StartsWith("S")
                        select row;

            DataView view = query.AsDataView();

            Console.WriteLine(view.Count); // Prints 0
            dt.Rows.Add("Sam");
            dt.Rows.Add("John");
            Console.WriteLine(view.Count); // Prints 1
            dt.Rows.Add("Sally");
            dt.Rows.Add("Mary");
            Console.WriteLine(view.Count); // Prints 2
            dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
            Console.WriteLine(view.Count); // Prints 1
        }
    }
}
```

> Does a DataView add an event to update when the underlying DataTable is modified?

This is an internal implementation detail, but it is plausible that this uses events.

Note that you can use the `DataTable.Copy` method to copy a `DataTable`, if you really want to create a snapshot of the `DataTable`.