# How to forbid to choose one of the combobox's items or not display it, or change Index property?

Tags: c#, .net

Let's imagine that I have next items in my cobobox:

```
myComboBox.Items.AddRange(new object[] {"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"});
```

What I need is that user won't be able to choose `item3`, or `item3` is invisible (won't be displayed) but `item4` still has `.SelectedIndex` property is equal to `3` (as 4th item).

Or second solution that fits my needs, after this:

```
myComboBox.Items.AddRange(new object[] {"item1", "item2", "item4"});
```

`item4` has `.SelectedIndex` property is equal to `3`.

Is there a way to do something like this ?

Comment: I think this was discussed here (at least for disabling): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002921/is-it-possible-to-disable-an-item-in-a-dropdownlist-combobox-in-c.  If that doesn't do it, you could implement this on the selection event.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `data-binding`, or the same technique you're using now, but in first case *do not add items you're going to negate access to*.

In other words fill combo with *only* relevant data to the current application state.

Answer (score 0):

Bind to a `DataView`, you should then be able to filter by any criteria and only choose items you want to appear in the list. This approach supports dynamic changes to the list, such as changing criteria on-the-fly or adding/removing items. See [.Net DataView and DataTable Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334877/net-dataview-and-datatable-binding).